# What are the radiation zone boundaries for?

Tags: plot-explanation, oblivion

In [*Oblivion*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1483013/) there are radiation zones that they cannot cross. Are these really radiation zones or are they boundaries to contain...

> each pair of clones? *Beech* said he's been to the radiation zones and if I recall, *Jack* (the main one) landed in a radiation zone only to find a clone of himself.

Comment: Wow, luckily I have seen Oblivion otherwise I would be mighty annoyed by that spoiler.

Comment: Tried to remove spoiler from title.

Comment: Well, you answered it pretty well yourself already, no? He went there and instead of dying or finding any kind of radiation he found something we was absolutely not supposed to know. So why wasn't he supposed to go there, because of radiation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "radiation zones" are only there to keep Jack and Victoria from going anywhere other than where they're supposed to. The reason for it being a "radiation" zone and not something else is to stop them from getting curious and wanting to explore what's out there (and finding out what's really going on). Nothing keeps you from doing that better than thinking that you'll die if you do.

Comment: That's what I thought but wanted to make sure I wasn't mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The radiation zones are there to keep Jack and Victoria unaware that they are not the only "jack and Victoria" on the planet. Had the zones not been fabricated, Jack would have been able to roam the planet, given the range of ship, and he would have eventually encountered his clone(s)

Comment: Not really sure how this answer adds anything to the one that's already been accepted....